# Touchscreen doesn't work on Emachines ez1711

Tags: touchscreen

After updating from 11.04 to 11.10 touchscreen on Emachines ez 1711 doesn't work. Mouse1 device disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with an update

> Touchscreen started to work after regular update.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot into 11.10 live CD. If touchscreen works here, something probably went wrong in the upgrade process. Do a full re-installation of Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Full re-installation of 11.10 has the same result:(

Comment: Touchscreen started to work after regular update.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it works again :)